# For Loop seeming to be running twice

Tags: java, sql, for-loop

EDIT: If I am asking this wrong, I am sorry.  My expected results would be to end up with this for loop running twice total.  I would expect only a:
System.out.println(inventory[0][1]);
System.out.println(inventory[1][1]);

I have what I thought was a simple for loop to pull from a database, and add each result to a String array.

```
while(rs3.next()) {
    for(int c = 0; c < iCount; c++) {
        inventory[c][0] = rs3.getString(10);                    
        inventory[c][1] = rs3.getString(9);                     

        System.out.println(inventory[c][1]); //#&(*& WHY IS THIS HAPPENING TWICE

        inventory[c][3] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(3));      
        inventory[c][6] = rs3.getString(6);                     
        inventory[c][10] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(12));    
        inventory[c][12] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(13));    
        inventory[c][31] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(14));    
        inventory[c][32] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(15));    
        inventory[c][34] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(16));    
        inventory[c][52] = rs3.getString(4);                    
        inventory[c][53] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(5)); 
        inventory[c][18] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(7));     
        inventory[c][29] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(8));     
        inventory[c][78] = Integer.toString(rs3.getInt(1));     
    }
}
```

int iCount is set at 2 in this example, which i checked using System.out.println().

The problem is, it is recording each value twice.(per loop, so a total of 4 times in this example)  This throws off other methods using this data.

I added the println(inventory[c][1]); to verify to myself that it was indeed doing this action twice PER LOOP of the for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood, but if `iCount` is `2`, then your `for` loop will execute twice for each iteration of your `while` loop. Which means, for example, your `System.out.println()` will execute twice.

Comment: It's like you're asking, "why does this for loop, that goes from i = 0 to i < 2, loop twice?

Comment: Set iCount=1 and check are you getting expected result. If answer is yes delete the question. Else add additional details

Comment: Tried to fix my question.  This is happening twice PER LOOP of the for loop.  i.e. it is happening 4 times rather than 1

Comment: You know that `inventory[0][1]` and `inventory[1][1]` are one and the same, right? They refer to the same String.

Comment: What is `inventory`?  Which loop is running more times than expected?  You have nested loops here.  When you step through in a debugger, *specifically* what happens?

Comment: @AJNeufeld is correct, I was unintentionally nesting loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you want:

```
int c = 0;
while(rs3.next()) {
    inventory[c][0] = rs3.getString(10);                    
    inventory[c][1] = rs3.getString(9);                     

    System.out.println(inventory[c][1]);

    // ... rest omitted for brevity

    c++;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is exactly it, and now I understand that the while itself is a loop.  I'm learning in baby-steps, but I'm learning.